# I do not know why the WiFi device is suddenly disabled?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet, connection, internet-connection

I do not know why this problem occurs suddenly and can not be solved even with repeated restarts. What's more interesting is that sometimes it happens on its own. However, my efforts have not been resolved after enabling and disabling the device several times.

WiFi display status. I'm still connected via USB.

[image]

I do not know if the Wi-Fi device is paused? The device is updated and the conditions for deleting and reinstalling are the same.

[image]

This device cannot start. (Code 10)

{Operation Failed}
The requested operation was unsuccessful.

And that's all Bill Gates is telling me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know why the WiFi device is suddenly disabled?  ......   my
> efforts have not been resolved after enabling and disabling the device
> several times

First: Remove the NIC in Device Manager (do not just disable.)

Second:  Restart the computer.  Windows may install the device (and may not).

Finally:  Download the current driver (another computer if need be) and install the driver.

IF, having removed the NIC device and cannot install again, the device may have a hardware error and may have failed.

In this event, get a USB Wireless NIC and install / use the USB NIC.